# Unable to create servicenow incident using API

Tags: rest, curl, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to create new incident using rest api.Getting below error message.

```
curl -X "PUT" "https://dev143368.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46bXYldTR*****" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"short_description\":\"Instance short description update from REST API\"}"
```

Error message:

> {"error":{"message":"Method not Supported","detail":"PUT method not supported for API"},"status":"failure"}

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is incorrect. A PUT is to modify a specific record so you need to specify the SYS_ID in the URL...

https://dev143368.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident/123456789

If you are trying to create a record, you should be using a POST.